# Regular Expression first coincidense

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to use regular expression to find a string of characters within a string.

I'm using

```
/TOMOGRAF.*..DE\g
```

and this is my string

```
TOMOGRAFIA AXUAL COMPUTADA DE ABDOMEN DE CUELLO
TOMOGRAFIA AXUAL COMPUTADA DE TORAX
```

the problem is that the firts line have two "DE" and I only need until the firts "DE"

Comment: Put ? after .* to make it non-greedy and make it /TOMOGRAF.*?..DE\g